# Why is my rails test failing? Hartl's Rails tutorial: chapter 13 microposts exercise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have a very specific quesiton about a test in one of the exercises. I have traced back the failure through all the different files and cannot see what is causing the problem. I will start with the failure message.

```
FAIL["test_profile_display", UsersProfileTest, 1.204680988099426]
 test_profile_display#UsersProfileTest (1.20s)
        <Michael Example | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
        <Michael ExampleMichael Example | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App>..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:UsersProfileTest>'
```

as can be seen the name from my fixtures file appears twice instead of once.

and the corresponding test which produces the failure:
test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersProfileTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include ApplicationHelper

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "profile display" do
    get user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select 'title', full_title(@user.name)
    assert_select 'h1', text: @user.name
    assert_select 'h1>img.gravatar'
    assert_match @user.microposts.count.to_s, response.body
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    @user.microposts.paginate(page: 1).each do |micropost|
      assert_match micropost.content, response.body
    end
  end
end
```

the offending line of the above code being

```
assert_select 'title', full_title(@user.name)
```

here is the fixtures file with the user :michael with name "Michael Example" that appears twice but should only appear once.

test/fixtures/users.yml

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
.
.
.
```

here is the code that this fixture is used in to create the title

app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      page_title + " | " + base_title
    end
  end
end
```

Why is the name from the users fixture appearing twice when the code states that is should appear only once in the page title?

EDIT:

app/views/layouts.application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= render 'layouts/rails_default' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
      <!--<div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>-->
      <% end %>

      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
```

EDIT 2 : users/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file where you call the `full_title` method?

Comment: @Jeff F. added app/views/layouts/application.html.erb in edit

Comment: Please show us your `users/show` file

Comment: @s3tjan users/show added as EDIT 2

Comment: I _EDIT 2_ is the same as _EDIT 1_

Comment: @s3tjan. sorry my bad. changed it

Comment: @Owen nothing sticks out to me. Try changing some values or adding some `puts` statements around to see if you find any clues. For example, in the `full_title` method, I'd be curious to see what's actually getting passed in there. Or run the page in a browser and see what the actual title is.

Comment: @ Jeff F. the actual title also prints the name twce. where would you suggest putting the "puts" statements?

Comment: Add one in the full_title method to check what's actually getting passed in there. You sure the user's name isn't getting changed somewhere in the User model?

Comment: @JeffF. do i add the "puts" in the view or the actual method. how can i see what is passed in to the method? and where inside the method do i add the puts and what am i putsing?

Comment: Add `puts page_title` as the first line in the `full_title` method and check for it in the output in your terminal.

Comment: @JeffF. F. i added it and there was no difference, page title was not visible. Surely i would have to add this line in the view for it to be visible. i do not understand the purpose of doing this. could you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

app/views/users/show.html.erb

`````
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>````
`````